# Make button size same as screen width

Tags: html, css, blogger

I am using this button code in a Blogger blog. But the problem is, in mobile, the width goes off the screen. How can I make it adjust to the user's screen size?

```
<div class="column" style="box-sizing: inherit; display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 0em; margin-top: 0em; padding-left: 1rem; padding-right: 1rem; vertical-align: middle; width: 650px;">
    <div class="margin-top centered" style="box-sizing: inherit; margin-top: 1.6rem; text-align: center;">
        <a class="btn" href="Link-Here" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; background-color: #00bd9a; border-radius: 2px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14) 0px 2px 2px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 5px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 3px 1px -2px; box-sizing: inherit; color: white; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; height: 42px; letter-spacing: 0.5px; line-height: 42px; padding: 0px 3rem; pointer-events: all; position: relative; text-decoration-line: none; text-transform: uppercase; vertical-align: middle; width: 537px;">Text Here</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seperated your html from the css and made some changes, using `%` instead of a fixed width.

Of course you could also use media queries for a responsive site

```css
.column {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.margin-top {
  margin-top: 1.6rem;
}

.centered {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  background-color: #00bd9a;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14) 0px 2px 2px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 5px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 3px 1px -2px;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 42px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  line-height: 42px;
  padding: 0px 1rem;
  pointer-events: all;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration-line: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="margin-top centered">
    <a class="btn" href="#" style="">
        Text Here
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for it. It was the solution I was needed.

Answer (score 2):

I would normally suggest using media query's to change the width of the button. Now it is set to a certain width, so if the screen is smaller, it goes outside of the screen. With a simple media query you can say that if the screen is narrower than `...px`, width is 100%.

Maybe try something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    btn {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it. It Worked.

Answer (score 1):

Quickest and easiest solution is to use bootstrap grid system. 
here is the modified version of your button html.

```
<div class="container" style="margin:10px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a class="btn" href="#">New</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's (https://codepen.io/faaiz/pen/WJBdOy) codepen link

Comment: Using Bootstrap for just this seems  a bit excessive.

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code :

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Block Level Buttons</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Button 2</button>

  <h2>Large Block Level Buttons</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Button 2</button>

  <h2>Small Block Level Buttons</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0vu83eru/3/

you can always use grid system for it like this:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6 ">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Click me!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

xs is for mobiles extra small devices as you have asked to manage it in mobile user screen's size. for bootstrap 4 replace col-xs-12 to col-12.